# R: ERROR - Error in rep.int(c(1, numeric(n)), n - 1L) : invalid 'times' value

Tags: r, regression

I've pored through responses here with similar errors and just can't seem to find a solution that works for me. I'm trying to set up some contrasts for a regression on a relatively small dataset (nrow = 378) and I'm getting the error in the title when trying to create the contrasts. The command I'm running is:

```
d$contrasts <- varContrasts(d$Media.Type,
                        Type = 'Dummy',
                        RefLevel = 4)
```

Anyone know what's going on here? This same code has worked for me with different datasets.

Edit: In response to Paul's comment, here is the output for dput(d$Media.Type)

```
    dput(d$Media.Type)
c("2", "3", "4", "3", "4", "4", "2", "4", "3", "3", "4", "3", 
"3", "4", "2", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", 
"3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "3", "1", "3", "4", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "4", "4", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "1", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "1", "1", "4", "4", "4", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "3", "3", "3", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", 
"1", "2", "4", "3", "3", "1", "2", "1", "1", "4", "4", "3", "1", 
"1", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "1", "3", "2", "4", "1", "1", 
"3", "3", "2", "1", "4", "3", "4", "1", "3", "1", "3", "2", "1", 
"2", "3", "2", "3", "4", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "1", "4", "1", "1", 
"2", "3", "4", "3", "3", "2", "1", "4", "1", "4", "2", "4", "3", 
"4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "4", "3", "4", "4", "2", "4", "4", "2", 
"4", "3", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "2", "1", "3", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "4", "4", "4", "4", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "4", "1", 
"1", "3", "1", "4", "4", "3", "2", "1", "4", "3", "1", "3", "2", 
"3", "4", "3", "2", "4", "2", "3", "2", "2", "1", "3", "1", "1", 
"3", "3", "4", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "2", 
"4", "1")
```

Comment: for me, invalid times usually means the times is NA. maybe here n is na? try running again but remove the NA from d$Media.Type

Answer (score 0):

`varContrasts` requires a `factor` but your data is `character`. Just cast it to a `factor`.

```
lmSupport::varContrasts(
  as.factor(x),
  Type = 'Dummy',
  RefLevel = 4
)
#>   1_v_4 2_v_4 3_v_4
#> 1     1     0     0
#> 2     0     1     0
#> 3     0     0     1
#> 4     0     0     0
```

---

Below is not the cause of your issue, but this error most commonly occurs when there are `NA`s.

Here is an example with no error.

```
x <- factor(1:5)
lmSupport::varContrasts(x, Type = 'Dummy', RefLevel = 4)
#> 1_v_4 2_v_4 3_v_4 5_v_4
#> 1     1     0     0     0
#> 2     0     1     0     0
#> 3     0     0     1     0
#> 4     0     0     0     0
#> 5     0     0     0     1
#> 1_v_4 2_v_4 3_v_4 5_v_4
#> 1     1     0     0     0
#> 2     0     1     0     0
#> 3     0     0     1     0
#> 4     0     0     0     0
#> 5     0     0     0     1
```

But if there is an `NA`, we get the error.

```
x2 <- c(x, NA)
lmSupport::varContrasts(x2, Type = 'Dummy', RefLevel = 4)
#> Error in rep.int(c(1, numeric(n)), n - 1L) : invalid 'times' value
```

These need to be handled in some way. For example, creating a new level, `Missing`.

```
x3 <- as.factor(tidyr::replace_na(x2, "Missing"))
#> lmSupport::varContrasts(x3, Type = 'Dummy', RefLevel = 4)
#> 1_v_4 2_v_4 3_v_4 5_v_4 Missing_v_4
#> 1           1     0     0     0           0
#> 2           0     1     0     0           0
#> 3           0     0     1     0           0
#> 4           0     0     0     0           0
#> 5           0     0     0     1           0
#> Missing     0     0     0     0           1
#> 1_v_4 2_v_4 3_v_4 5_v_4 Missing_v_4
#> 1           1     0     0     0           0
#> 2           0     1     0     0           0
#> 3           0     0     1     0           0
#> 4           0     0     0     0           0
#> 5           0     0     0     1           0
#> Missing     0     0     0     0           1
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I've actually tried omitting NAs, though, and gotten the same error. I've also visually inspected the data and found no NAs.

Comment: Can you share the data? Add the result of `dput(d)` to the question.

Comment: Sure! I don't think the full output of dput(d) will be helpful because there are 393 columns in this dataset, but I added the output for dput(d$Media.Type)

Comment: D'oh! Thank you so much dude!